# how to get longest repeating string in substring from suffix tree

Tags: string, algorithm, perl, tree, suffix-tree

I need to find the longest repeating string in substring. Let's say I have string `"bannana"`

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem) following:

> In computer science, the longest repeated substring problem is the
>   problem of finding the longest substring of a string that occurs at
>   least twice. In the figure with the string "ATCGATCGA$", the longest
>   repeated substring is "ATCGA"

So I assume that for string `"bannana"` there are two equally long substrings (if not correct me please): `"an"` and `"na"`.

Wikipedia also [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem) that for this purpose suffix trees are used. To be more specific [here](https://www.quora.com/Write-a-program-to-return-the-longest-repeating-substring-in-a-string) is quotation how to do it (this seems to me more understable than definition on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem)):

> build a Suffix tree, then find the highest node with at least 2
>   descendants.

I've found several implementations of suffix trees. Following code is taken from [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Suffix_tree#Perl):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

sub classify {
    my ($f, $h) = (shift, {});
    for (@_) { push @{$h->{$f->($_)}}, $_ }
    return $h;
}
sub suffixes {
    my $str = shift;
    map { substr $str, $_ } 0 .. length($str) - 1;
}
sub suffix_tree {
    return +{} if @_ == 0;
    return +{ $_[0] => +{} } if @_ == 1;
    my $h = {};
    my $classif = classify sub { substr shift, 0, 1 }, @_;
    for my $key (sort keys %$classif) {
        my $subtree = suffix_tree(
            grep "$_", map { substr $_, 1 } @{$classif->{$key}}
        );
        my @subkeys = keys %$subtree;
        if (@subkeys == 1) {
            my $subkey = shift @subkeys;
            $h->{"$key$subkey"} = $subtree->{$subkey};
        } else { $h->{$key} = $subtree }
    }
    return $h;
}

print +Dumper suffix_tree suffixes 'bannana$';
```

for string `"bannana"` it returns following tree:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '$' => {},
          'n' => {
                   'a' => {
                            'na$' => {},
                            '$' => {}
                          },
                   'nana$' => {}
                 },
          'a' => {
                   '$' => {},
                   'n' => {
                            'a$' => {},
                            'nana$' => {}
                          }
                 },
          'bannana$' => {}
        };
```

Another implementation is online from [here](http://www.allisons.org/ll/AlgDS/Tree/Suffix/), for string `"bannana"` it returns following tree:

```
 7: a
 5: ana
 2: annana
 1: bannana
 6: na
 4: nana
 3: nnana

     |(1:bannana)|leaf
tree:|
     |      |(4:nana)|leaf
     |(2:an)|
     |      |(7:a)|leaf
     |
     |     |(4:nana)|leaf
     |(3:n)|
     |     |(5:ana)|leaf
3 branching nodes
```

Questions:

1. How can I get from those graphs `"an"` and `"na"` strings?
2. As you can see trees are different, are they equivalent or not, if yes why they are different, if not which algorithm is correct?
3. If perl implementation is wrong is there any working implementation for perl/python?
4. I've read about Ukkonen's algorithm which is also mentioned on page with 2nd example  (I did not catch if the online version is using this algorithm or not), does any of the mentioned examples using this algorithm? If not, is used algorithm slower or has any drawbacks compared to Ukkonen?

Comment: It is not quite clear how the first implemetation managed to convert `bannana` to `banana`.

Comment: The first implementation is dubious: is it `bannana` or `banana`? The second looks wrong: it has 5 leafs, but `bannana` has 7 letters, so it should have 7 leafs, according to the definition.

Comment: Your notation is also confusing. Suffix trees usually label the edges, not the nodes. But you seem to label the nodes, so what do your labels represent?

Comment: sorry guys, my fault I've fixed `bannana` vs `banana`. It is `bannana` @IVlad to be honest I have no idea. My initial goal is to find longest repeating substring, suffix tree is just a "tool" to do it, how exactly they are working I do not know. But what I understood, is that the answer to my problem.

Comment: What you should do is look at the algorithms for computing the longest common prefix array (usually used with suffix arrays) from a suffix tree.

Answer (score 1):

*1. How can I get from those graphs "an" and "na" strings?*

> build a Suffix tree, then find the highest node with at least 2 descendants.

`string-node` is concatenate strings for every node from root to this node. `highest node` is node with maximum length `string-node`.

See tree in my answer for second question. `(3:n)` have 2 descendants and path to node is `(2:a)->(3:n)`, concatenate is `an`. And also for `(5:a)` get `na`.

*2. As you can see trees are different, are they equivalent or not, if yes why they are different, if not which algorithm is correct?*

These trees are different. Rebuild second tree for string `"bannana$"` (
as in the first tree):

```
 8: $
 7: a$
 5: ana$
 2: annana$
 1: bannana$
 6: na$
 4: nana$
 3: nnana$

     |(1:bannana$)|leaf
tree:|
     |     |     |(4:nana$)|leaf
     |     |(3:n)|
     |     |     |(7:a$)|leaf
     |(2:a)|
     |     |(8:$)|leaf
     |
     |     |(4:nana$)|leaf
     |(3:n)|
     |     |     |(6:na$)|leaf
     |     |(5:a)|
     |     |     |(8:$)|leaf
     |
     |(8:$)|leaf
5 branching nodes
```

*3. If perl implementation is wrong is there any working implementation for perl/python?*

I don't know Perl, but the tree is built correctly.

*4. I've read about Ukkonen's algorithm which is also mentioned on page with 2nd example (I did not catch if the online version is using this algorithm or not), does any of the mentioned examples using this algorithm? If not, is used algorithm slower or has any drawbacks compared to Ukkonen?*

I said earlier that I don't know Perl, but it's a line in first algorthim means that it works at least `O(n^2)` (`n` it is length string):

```
map { substr $str, $_ } 0 .. length($str) - 1;
```

Ukkonen's algorithm works linear time `O(n)`.

First algorithm also recursive which may affect used memory.